# android:background - "?attr/actionBarItemBackground" .. How it works?

Tags: android-widget, actionbarsherlock

I have seen two ways to set background for Android App screen.

case A:: android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"

case B:: android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_settings"

How do android:background functions in the case A? I searched code, but not able to figure out where "actionBarItemBackground" exists. I understood case B

Comment: By to By, I am using ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case A is a reference to a style attribute. It allows you to reference a particular piece of style information without knowing its actual value. There are a lot of Android-defined attributes that are used to style the Android UI, but you can also define you own attributes.

[`actionBarItemBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarItemBackground) is one such attribute. There are two ways you can use this attribute:

1. You can reference it to make the look and feel of UI elements consistent with action bar items:

   ```xml
   <com.mycompany.MyView
       android:id="@+id/myView"
       android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"/>
   ```
2. You can define a theme and set the value of this attribute to override the default L&F for your app:

   ```xml
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
       <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">#383c44</item>
   </style>
   ```

Here are some pointers to the Android documentation:

For styles an themes see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

For a list of all attributes see:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

For defining your own attributes there is no documentation. Have a look at one of the `attrs.xml` files in the SDK (e.g. under `platforms\android-17\data\res\values`) to see how style attributes are declared. You can declare attributes in the same way by putting an `attrs.xml` file in your `res\values` folder. You can then use these attributes in your own styles and themes.